# R purrr map2 to change column name - problem with spacing in column name

Tags: r, rename, purrr

I am working with some data from external sources which comes with a space in one of its variable names ("Pseudo ID"). I am trying to use purrr::map to change this variable name in all the datasets, but R seems to have problems recognising this variable. I do not want to keep changing variable names one by one... I wonder if anyone can spot the solution?

```
    library(tidyverse)

    # Mock data:
    set.seed(1)
    sampledata<- data.frame(
         ID = sample(1:2), 
         name = sample(letters, 2, replace = TRUE))
    colnames(sampledata)[1] <- "Pseudo ID"

    # List of mock data:
    datalist <- list(sampledata, sampledata)

    # Set name in each dataset in the list using map
    map(datalist, set_names, nm="PatientID") # BUT HOW CAN I RENAME A SPECIFIC COLUMN - 'Pseudo ID'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` and `set_names` from `purrr` here.

```
set.seed(1)
sampledata<- data.frame(ID = sample(1:2), name = sample(letters, 2, replace = TRUE))
colnames(sampledata)[1] <- "Pseudo ID"
datalist <- list(sampledata, sampledata)

library(purrr)
map(datalist, ~ set_names(.x, nm = replace(
  names(.x), names(.x) == "Pseudo ID", "PatientID"
)))
#[[1]]
#  PatientID name
#1         1    o
#2         2    x

#[[2]]
#  PatientID name
#1         1    o
#2         2    x
```

If you want to assign different names, use `map2`

```
new_id_names <- c("PatientID_1", "PatientID_2")
map2(.x = datalist, .y = new_id_names, ~ set_names(.x, nm = replace(
  names(.x), names(.x) == "Pseudo ID", .y
)))
```

Comment: There are other variables in the 'sampledata' besides "Pseudo ID", I wonder if there's a way to specify this?

Comment: @Dani Can you update your question and give a minimal example?

Comment: Hi markus, thank you - please find my question updated

Comment: @Dani Have updated my answer. Let me know if it is working now.

Comment: Hi markus, it works perfectly. The purrr package seems powerful but it is difficult to get my head around it still. Thank you very much for your help.